# Are smart pointers thread safe?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, smart-pointers

A smart pointer is an abstract data type that simulates a pointer while providing added features such as automatic memory management or bounds checking.

My question is, are they thread-safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various different smart pointer objects provide various different degrees of thread safety. You have to check the documentation for the individual implementation carefully to see what level of thread safety it provides.

The most common question is specifically about `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`. These provide standard thread safety for individual pointer instances. That is, one thread must not access a `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` while another thread is, or might be, modifying that exact same `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` object. However, they provide full thread safety for distinct pointers that reference the same object. So one thread can modify a `shared_ptr` while another thread is accessing a `shared_ptr` to that same underlying object whose lifetime is managed by the smart pointers.

Comment: I suppose thread safety applies to distinct `shared_ptr` instances (as you say), but not to the object pointed at

Comment: @LWimsey yes, that is the case.